# Universal and Existential quantifier in Propositional logic

Tags: discrete-mathematics, propositional-calculus, quantifiers

**The following paragraph is an excerpt from Discrete Mathematics book of Kenneth Rosen 7edition**

> The restriction of a universal quantification is the same as the
>   universal quantification of a conditional statement. For instance, ∀x
>   < 0 (x<sup>2</sup> > 0) is another way of expressing ∀x(x < 0 →
>   x<sup>2</sup>> 0). On the other hand, the restriction of an
>   existential quantification is the same as the existential
>   quantification of a conjunction. For instance, ∃z > 0 (z<sup>2</sup> =
>   2) is another way of expressing ∃z(z > 0 ∧ z<sup>2</sup> = 2).

**Ques : Why universal quantification is same as universal quantification of a conditional statement whereas existential quantification is same as existential quantification of a conjunction?**

Please provide proper details. Thank You.

Comment: I sort of don't know how to answer other than the English interpretation.  $\forall x < 0 (x^2 >0)$ would read "for all $x$ less than zero, $x^2$ is greater than zero".  In other words, the "statement" is only valid when $x$ is less than zero--for all $x$ less than zero.  Thus if we look at _all_ $x$ then the statement is that "if $x$ is less than zero then $x^2$ is greater than zero"...continued...

Comment: If we translate e.g. $∃z < 0 (z^2 = 2)$ as $∃z(z <  0 \to z^2 = 2)$ instead of $∃z(z <  0 ∧ z^2 = 2)$, what we get is that $∃z <  0 (z^2 = 2)$ will be true also for the *natural* numbers.

Comment: On the other hand, $\exists z > 0 (z^2 = 2)$ would translate to "there exists a $z$ greater than zero such that $z^2$ equals 2".  In this case we _must_ find (at least one) $z > 0$ such that $z^2 = 2$.  Thus to be true we _must_ be able to find a $z$ such that _both_ $z > 0$ _and_ $z^2 = 2$.  It would be completely incorrect to write $\exists z (z > 0 \rightarrow z^2 = 2)$.  That's _easy_ to satisfy--just choose any $z \leq 0$ then the condition is trivially true.  The universal requires a condition _for all_ values and the existential requires the existence of the condition.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Think on these lines.

$(1)$ All humans die.

Equivalent form : For every $x$, *if* $x$ is human, *then* $x$ must die. **(An implication)**

$(2)$. Some animals are color blind.

Equivalent form: There exists some $x$ such that, $x$ is an animal *and* $x$ is color blind. **(A conjunction)**

Comment: That did for me, Thank You.
Sometimes answers are just before you and you cannot see them.
Thank You

Comment: @Navneet Srivastava...my pleasure